# Type which matches any value of a constant object

Tags: typescript, types, keyof

Given this `const`:

```js
const beatsByDuration = {
    q: 1,
    h: 2,
    w: 4,
    1: 4 / 1,
    2: 4 / 2,
    4: 4 / 4,
    8: 4 / 8,
    16: 4 / 16,
};
```

These types are equivalent.

```js
type Duration = 'q' | 'h' | 'w' | '1' | '2' | '4' | '8' | '16';
type Duration = keyof typeof beatsByDuration
```

How can I define a type which matches any of the values of the object (`1 | 2 | 4 | 0.5 | 0.25`) ?

(I see several similar-ish questions, but none exactly like this. I don't want to just match the *types* of the values, but the values themselves. And my object is not a type, it's an object.)

Comment: Does **[this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBARgUwIZQgIQJ4BECuAnFAS3BgF4YBvAKBlpgEcAuGARgBoa6ALZgJg7owA7swAsAuizEwA9Kwm1e0uf061RymOLUwAHJt0LWANk0tjHAL4BuKlSgYADghgA1JABscCAPIAzAB4AFQA+MhgggG0AawQMED8IgF1bB2cYNGRUdy8XchzvfwC0hAT4LPRsfCJwEOsgA)** help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible with a [`const`-assertio](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions)n if you defined your values as literal values instead of expressions. E.g. `4 / 16` is simply inferred as `number` since the actual value (`0.25`) is determined at runtime.

```
const beatsByDuration = {
    q: 1,
    h: 2,
    w: 4,
    1: 4,
    2: 2,
    4: 1,
    8: 0.5,
    16: 0.25,
} as const;

type Values = typeof beatsByDuration[keyof typeof beatsByDuration];
// type Values = 1 | 2 | 4 | 0.5 | 0.25
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBARgUwIZQgIQJ4BECuAnFAS3BgF4YBvAKBlpgEcAuGARgBoa6ALZgJg7owA7swAsAuizETavPjJijm7TrQAczAAwA6AKwKWANi3be%20qgF8YSCDFCQoAbipUoGAA4IYANSQAbHARbcjdPEAAzeGRUTFwCKGIwAG0AawQMCJhQhEzEFHRsfCJwAF1nAHpyugA9AH4gA)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that made a difference.